# Application Insights Metrics Explorer annoyances

Tags: azure-application-insights

"Metric Explorers" on an Azure portal dashboard are quite flexible.

To configure them is, however, a bit painful at times.

[image]

With the terms in above image:

- How do I change the order of my charts within an explorer?
- How do I copy a chart or a whole explorer?
- Is there a textual definition I can get or give? Is there other software for a better editing experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change the order of my charts within an explorer?

Unfortunately there isn't a direct way to reorder the charts within an explorer. As a workaround you could however, delete them and add them again so that they appear at the bottom. Remember everytime you click 'Add New Chart', it will add it at the bottom.

Also please note that all graphical charts (Line, Area and Bar) appear above whereas a Grid chart will always appear at the bottom. So here's an even simpler hack that you could use: If there's any chart that you want to send to them bottom, change it's type to Grid and then change it back again. It'll get pushed to the end.

> How do I copy a chart or a whole explorer?

You can click on `More` and then click `Save Favorite` which will save the whole metrics explorer blade (including all custom charts). You can give it a name and even save as a copy to create multiple copies of the whole explorer.

To access favorites, you'll have to go to the Overview tab and click on `More` followed by `Favorites` again. Favorites can be shared as well as personal.

> Is there a textual definition I can get or give? Is there other software for a better editing experience?

There isn't a textual definition that you can provide for the charts. If you'd like to see this feature, you can add to the [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights) or open an issue on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home).

There isn't a software available for creating charts in the metrics explorer blade. However, there are alternatives for visualizing and querying data. You can take a look at [Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) if you prefer writing queries to filter insights and telemetry data. It has a very easy-to-learn query language which can help create meaningful charts very easily. There is a lot of tooling and support to push these charts to Power BI as well.

Hope this helps!